# Post JSON Data From Javascript To Java

Tags: java, javascript, json, jetty, apache-camel

I'm in need of some desperate help. I've been at this for 4 hours, and I'm getting pretty worn out. :/ Here's my situation:

I have a Javascript application that is making a POST request (using jQuery $.post) to an external site. On the external site I have Apache Camel running with Jetty to expose it to the web. The web services I wrote in Camel expect JSON data for all of the requests. For instance, one request needs an id, so I send it `{"id": 10}`.

Here's my issue: it doesn't work from Javascript. I have a few different tools that will send post requests for me (like the Poster extension for browsers). If I use Poster and set the body to `{"id": 10}`, it works just fine. I get that exact string in the service.

But, if I post from Javascript, I get something different. Posting the JSON object will give me the string "id=10" on my service side. (It's OK for this scenario, but I will need actual JSON objects eventually.) If I stringify the JSON object, I get the JSON string, only all of the characters are escaped. (Ex. "%7Bid%33...").

I swear I've tried every method possible for posting the data, but I either get the weird already parsed JSON, or the escaped string (or nothing at all). Is there some way I can have Javascript NOT parse the JSON object and just send it (like my posting tool does)? If not, is there a safe, efficient way to un-escape the JSON string that I get?

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers here gave me a few hints, but ultimately, it was a lot of tweaking before it would work correctly. I had to do 3 things:

1. Add `processData: false`.
2. Turn the JSON object into a JSON string. The request wouldn't fire if I left it as an object (even if I changed `contentType` to `application/json`).
3. Change the `contentType to` `text/plain`. This sent it as a raw string.

And that's what did the trick. I now get the JSON string I want on the server side.

Comment: You should see what you need to change to make application/json work. The contentType really is not text/plain.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like we need a little bit more information, but take a look at this javascript plugin. It may be your solution: https://github.com/flowersinthesand/jquery-stringifyJSON

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery.ajax and setting `processData` to `false` (defaults to `true`):

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/where/to/post',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {"id": 10},
  processData: false
});
```

Usually, jQuery converts anything in `data` to query string format like `id=10`. The `processData` flag tells jQuery to interpret it literally as a json hashmap.

Comment: This somewhat did it. I did have to use processData, but putting it in like you said would cause it not to fire the request. I had to add a few other things to make it work. You can see in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Posting the JSON object will give me the string "id=10" on my service side.

Javascript does not do your this conversion, so your server does it.

It is likely that your server reacts differently based on the `content-type` of your POST e.g. `application/json` vs `text/plain` or `text/html`, a common feature of REST based services.

Comment: No, it was definitely on the Javascript side. Camel and Jetty were doing some processing, but I could get it as a raw string if necessary.